# Incompatible row dimensions when using passthrough in GridSearch over sklearn Pipeline with FeatureUnion

Tags: scikit-learn, feature-extraction, gridsearchcv, countvectorizer, scikit-learn-pipeline

I am trying to do grid search over a [sklearn pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) that uses a custom transformer in a pipeline with [FeatureUnion](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion.html). It works fine when the pipeline uses the custom transformer class in FeatureUnion; however, it fails when the custom class is ignored in the pipeline by setting `passthrough` in the grid search parameters.

The full pipeline is defined as follows:

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion

ngram_vectorizer = Pipeline([
    ("vectorizer", CountVectorizer(analyzer="char_wb", ngram_range=(1,3))), 
    ("tfidf", TfidfTransformer())
])

pipe_full = Pipeline(
    [
        ("features", FeatureUnion(
            [
                ("ngrams", ngram_vectorizer),
                ("lengths", TextLengthExtractor())
            ]
            )
        ),
        ("classifier", MultinomialNB())
    ]
)
```

The custom transformer class `TextLengthExtractor` simply computes the number of characters from an input string:

```py
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
class TextLengthExtractor(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    
    def fit(self, X, y = None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y = None):
        string_lengths = np.array([len(doc) for doc in X])
        return string_lengths.reshape(-1,1)
```

The tuning parameters for grid search are defined through a dictionary `params`. Importantly, the parameters for the custom `TextLengthExtractor` contain the `passthrough` option to ignore the entire `features__lengths` step from the pipeline (see also the [sklearn's documentation on pipelines](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html)):

```py
params = {
    "features__lengths": [TextLengthExtractor(), "passthrough"],
    "features__ngrams__vectorizer__ngram_range" : [(1,3), (2,6)],
}
```

When the pipeline is fit on the following dummy data

```py
X_train_dummy = ["a", "ab", "a bc", "aaaaa", "b ab cc b", "ba", "baba", "cc bb aa", "c", "bca"]
y_train_dummy = [1,0,1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
pipe_full.fit(X_train_dummy, y_train_dummy)
```

it can be seen that the `lengths` step of the `FeatureUnion` pipeline works as expected:

```py
pipe_full["features"].get_params()["lengths"].transform(X_train_dummy)
# gives the following output of shape (10,1)
# array([[1], [2], [4], [5], [9], [2], [4], [8], [1], [3]])
```

However - and now comes the problem - when grid search is performed as follows:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipe_full, params, cv=5, n_jobs=-1, verbose=10)
grid_search.fit(X_train_dummy, y_train_dummy)
```

all fits that ignore the `lengths` step (as defined by the `passthrough` option from `params["features__lengths"]` throw the following error:

```py
5 fits failed out of a total of 10.
The score on these train-test partitions for these parameters will be set to nan.
If these failures are not expected, you can try to debug them by setting error_score='raise'.

Below are more details about the failures:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
5 fits failed with the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\dev\NameClassification\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 686, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File "C:\dev\NameClassification\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 378, in fit
    Xt = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params_steps)
  File "C:\dev\NameClassification\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 336, in _fit
    X, fitted_transformer = fit_transform_one_cached(
  File "C:\dev\NameClassification\venv\lib\site-packages\joblib\memory.py", line 349, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\dev\NameClassification\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 870, in _fit_transform_one
    res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
  File "C:\dev\NameClassification\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 1162, in fit_transform
    return self._hstack(Xs)
  File "C:\dev\NameClassification\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 1216, in _hstack
    Xs = sparse.hstack(Xs).tocsr()
  File "C:\dev\NameClassification\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\_construct.py", line 532, in hstack
    return bmat([blocks], format=format, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\dev\NameClassification\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\_construct.py", line 665, in bmat
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: blocks[0,:] has incompatible row dimensions. Got blocks[0,1].shape[0] == 1, expected 8.
```

I do understand that both steps require identical row dimensions for both `ngrams` and `lengths` in the `FeatureUnion`, where the number of rows in the extracted feature matrices must equal the number of samples in the respective split. However, I have no idea how to control the shape of matrices when ignoring the `lengths` part of `FeatureUnion` using the `passthrough` option in the gird search params.

I have found any solution to the problem on SE or any other sklearn related resource. Does anyone have an idea on how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution to the problem: To ignore an individual step in a `FeatureUnion`, the string `drop` rather than `passthrough` must be used. According to sklearn's documentation of [FeatureUnion](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion.html):

> Parameters of the transformers may be set using its name and the parameter name separated by a '__'. A **transformer may** be replaced entirely by setting the parameter with its name to another transformer, **removed by setting to 'drop'** or disabled by setting to 'passthrough' (features are passed without transformation).

An example of dropping an entire transformer in `FeatureUnion` is also shown in [sklearn's user guide on pipelines](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#id1).

In conclusion, to solve my problem, I had to replace `passthrough` with `drop` in the grid search parameter dictionary as follows

Change from

```py
params = {
    "features__lengths": [TextLengthExtractor(), "passthrough"],
    "features__ngrams__vectorizer__ngram_range" : [(1,3), (2,6)],
}
```

to

```py
params = {
    "features__lengths": [TextLengthExtractor(), "drop"],
    "features__ngrams__vectorizer__ngram_range" : [(1,3), (2,6)],
}
```